# Coding - Find a bitwise XOR for a range of numbers in java

Tags: java

Find a bitwise XOR for a range for.e.g (5,8) --> 5 bitXOR 6 | 7 bitXOR 8
                                                        3  bitXOR 15
                                                            12
Expected worst time Complexity - O(log(n))
Expected worst space Complexity - O(1)

I have written the below code, could you please help me to improve it?

```
static List<Integer> list;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int bitXORProduct = solution(5,8);
        System.out.println(bitXORProduct);
    }
    public static int solution(int M, int N) {
        if (isValidatedInput(M, N)) {
            int lastXOR = M;
            int currentXOR = 0;
            try {
                for (int i = M; i < N; i++) {
                    currentXOR = computeXOR(lastXOR, i + 1);
                    lastXOR = currentXOR;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Error Found : -" + e);
            }
            return lastXOR;
        }
        System.out.println("Input is not in the range or valid");
        return -1;
    }
    private static boolean isValidatedInput(int M, int N) {
        if (0 <= M && 0 <= N && M <= Math.pow(10, 9) && N <= Math.pow(10, 9) && M <= N) {
            return true;
        } else
            return false;
    }
    private static Integer computeXOR(Integer m, Integer n) {
        return m ^ n;
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried ^ operator?
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html

Comment: @HưngChu look at the last method.

Comment: Maybe https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is best place for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has constant time complexity of O(2) and constant space complexity as O(8)
You can use a solution as below,

```
public class XorOps {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getXor(5, 8));
    }

    static long getMod4(int a) {
        long[] res = {a, 1, a + 1, 0};
        return res[a % 4];
    }

    static long getXor(int a, int b) {
        return getMod4(b) ^ getMod4(a - 1);
    }
}
```

For a general range of [5,8]. We can use `getXor()` to find the XOR for [0,5-1]=[0,4] and [0,8]. Since any value XOR'd with itself is zero, the f(5-1) just cancels out all the values in the XOR run less than 5, leaving you with the XOR of the range [5,8].